# Find k-th minimum sum of every possible subset

Tags: algorithm, sorting, subset

Last time I found interesting problem, and I got stuck on it.

Given n numbers a[1], ..., a[n] in ascending order and number k (1 <= n,k <= 10^5).

Let say that we're sorting every possible subset of given sequence by sum.
We have to find sum of k-th such subset.

For example:
n = 4, k = 8
a = { 2, 7, 8, 15 }

1: { 2 }, sum = 2
2: { 7 }, sum = 7
3: { 8 }, sum = 8
4: { 2, 7 }, sum = 9
5: { 2, 8 }, sum = 10
6: { 7, 8 }, sum = 15
7: { 15 }, sum = 15
8: { 2, 15 }, sum = 17
...
k = 8, so answer = 17 (subset {2,15}).

Of course we can generate every possible subset and whole solution runs in O(2^n * n), but I'm searching for something more smart - linear, or at least O(nk).

Comment: Nonnegative numbers?

Comment: Yep, 1 <= a[i] <= 10^9.

Comment: How do you differentiate order for sets that have the same sum?

Comment: @C.B. It doesn't matter, result should be the same.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506675/14578

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Going to assume nonempty subsets for simplicity. Handling the empty subset is a line or two.)

Given a nonempty subset of indices `S`, define the *children* of `S` to be `S \ {max(S)} U {max(S) + 1}` and `S U {max(S) + 1}`. Starting with `{1}`, the child relation forms a tree that includes every nonempty subset of positive integers.

```
{1}
|  \
{2} {1,2}______
|  \     \     \
{3} {2,3} {1,3} {1,2,3}
```

Keyed by the sum of corresponding array elements, this tree is a min-heap. If you compute the keys carefully (by adding and subtracting rather than summing from scratch) and implement the min-heap deletion lazily, then you get an O(k log k)-time algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Very smart idea. How many vertices such a tree would have? And after some deletions should new vertices be added to leaves?

Comment: @JacobScott It's going to have `2^n-1` vertices, which is way too many for explicit representation. Instead, every time you delete a node, insert its children; then the space requirement will be O(k).

Comment: Thanks! Last question: in each vertices I have to keep an array. After each deletion and insertion tree has one more vertex. It takes O(k²) memory, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @JacobScott If you just need the sum in the end, keep the largest value and the sum. If you need the whole array, store a pointer to the original parent; then you can reconstruct the set by walking the parent pointer chain.

Comment: wow, great idea. The sketch does help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Could you extend this for unbounded subsets? ie. Each element can be picked as many times as we want.

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary definitely, the root is still `[1]`, and the children of `S` are `S + [max(S)]` and `S + [max(S) + 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

In his answer, David essentially employed Dijkstra's algorithm on a carefully constructed directed graph of subsets.

A bit more naive approach that I initially came up with is to apply Dijkstra directly to the hypercube of subsets. In other words, start with an empty subset and repeatedly try adding each previously missing array element (transitions of the form `S -> {S U {v} for v in [n] \ S}`.

The complexity of this approach will be worse since the maximum degree is O(n), implying that we may explore as many as O(nk) vertices of the hypercube. It leads to an unpleasant overall complexity of O(nk log nk).

David's construction differs from the naive approach in having a maximum degree of 2, guaranteeing that we will only explore O(k) vertices (the smallest k and at most 2k their children). I figured that this answer could be helpful for those struggling to understand why we need this somewhat not straightforward construction.